# how to insert a word and use it to make comparison in if condition in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i want to use the word i insert to use it to make comparison in if condition to show some word it the comparison is true.
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char u[5];
    cout<<"    p     " <<"      c      "<<"      U    "<<endl;
    cout<<" pepsi=5"<<"      coca=3"<<"       7-UP=2"<<endl;
    cout<<"CHOOSE your drink"<<endl;
    cin>>u;
    if (u=="pepsi")
        cout<<"your choice is pepsi and ur bill is 5 ";
}
```

Comment: Use `std::string u;`, and your code should work.  (As it is, if the uesr enters `pepsi`, you have undefined behavior.)

Comment: Try to work a little harder on formatting. Also, either don't use a C-string for user input (use std::string) or have a larger buffer. What happens when they type `coca-cola`?

Comment: @crashmstr Even `"pepsi"` is too long here.

Comment: you may want to have a look to what the operator == actually does. So It would be clear to you why "James Kanze" answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

First in the future I would suggest trying to be more specific on what your problem is and what you don't understand. Just saying I want to do X and here is my code is giving us very little to work with and we are basically just guessing on what you are having problems with.

Now on to what I believe you are having problems with (I am assuming since you didn't tell us what is going wrong).

In this case you are using a character array with a length of 5. Now when you use character arrays you need to take into account that all the reasonable inputs that that variable might store will actually fit into that character array.

Let's look at pepsi. You might think it would fit but in fact it doesn't because you are forgetting about the null character that is added on the end. This is what it looks like.

```
u[0] = 'p' 
u[1] = 'e'
u[2] = 'p' 
u[3] = 's' 
u[4] = 'i'
u[5] = '\0'
```

So as you can see there is actually 6 characters in this word which will cause a overflow. I am assuming this is your problem.

Now how do we fix this? As others have said in the comments if you are using C++ it is probably better for you to use std::string for this problem since it will hide from you most of the problems you have to do deal with when using C style string (What you are using now). Then once you feel more comfortable with the language you can come back and revisit C style strings.

With std::string it would look something like this. Remember that when testing strings case matters (IE "string" is not the same as "String").

```
std::string choice;
std::cin >> choice;
if (choice == "pepsi")
{
    std::cout << "You selected pepsi!" << std::endl;
}
```

Hope that helps a little and fixes your problems.